# Nhibernate, no session or session was closed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, nhibernate, autofac

Всем привет!
Ошибка:

```
[LazyInitializationException: Initializing[DetalSt.Default.Models.MenuItem#13]-failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: DetalSt.Default.Models.MenuItem.MenuItems, no session or session was closed]
   NHibernate.Collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.ThrowLazyInitializationException(String message) +199
   NHibernate.Collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.ThrowLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected() +70
   NHibernate.Collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.ReadSize() +59
```

Суть в том, что я пытаюсь дотянуться до коллекции сущностей в подгруженной сущности:

```
public class MenuItem : DetalSt.Default.Models.IEntity 
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Uid { get; set; }
        public virtual string Header { get; set; }
        public virtual string Url { get; set; }
        public virtual int QueueNumber { get; set; }
        public virtual bool Main { get; set; }
        public virtual MenuItem Parent { get; set; }
        private IList<MenuItem> _menuItems;
        public virtual IList<MenuItem> MenuItems
        {
            get
            {
                return _menuItems ?? (_menuItems = new List<MenuItem>());
            }
            set { _menuItems = value; }
        }
    }
```

Разумеется, если я в маппинге укажу Not.LazyLoad(), то все получится.

Доп.инф. Сессий я управляю следующим образом:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
            {
                var unitOfWork = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUnitOfWork>() as UnitOfWork;
                if (unitOfWork == null)
                    return;

                HttpContext.Current.Items.Add(nhSessionKey, unitOfWork);
                unitOfWork.OpenSession();
                unitOfWork.BeginTransaction();
            }

protected void Application_EndRequest()
            {
                var unitOfWork = HttpContext.Current.Items[nhSessionKey] as UnitOfWork;
                if (unitOfWork == null)
                    return;

                unitOfWork.Commit();
            }
```

UnitOfWork регистрирую в автофаке.
Сессия на момент запроса есть, при этом падает с ошибкой, что её нет. Прошу помощи.

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private static readonly ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
        private ITransaction _transaction;

        public ISession Session { get; private set; }

        static UnitOfWork()
        {
            _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012.ConnectionString(@"").ShowSql())
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<DetalSt.Default.Models.UserMap>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false, true))
            .BuildSessionFactory();
        }

    public void OpenSession()
    {
        Session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }

    public void BeginTransaction()
    {
        _transaction = Session.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_transaction != null && _transaction.IsActive)
                _transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            if (_transaction != null && _transaction.IsActive)
                _transaction.Rollback();

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            Session.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public void Rollback()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_transaction != null && _transaction.IsActive)
                _transaction.Rollback();
        }
        finally
        {
            Session.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: >Сессия на момент запроса есть -- а она Open? И да, в каком месте кода падает исключение?

Comment: isOpen == true; Падает при попытке обращения к свойству MenuItems объекта public class MenuItem : DetalSt.Default.Models.IEntity

Comment: А в каком месте кода вы к этому свойству обращатесь? как код вокруг выглядит?

Comment: Ну например 'private MenuItemManager _menuItemManager;

        public AdminPanelController(MenuItemManager manager)
        {
            _menuItemManager = manager;
        }' - инъекция менеджера.

'public virtual IList<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> condition)
        {
            using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            {
                return session.Query<T>().Where(condition).ToList();
            }
        }' - метод менеджера;
.

Comment: И: var item = _menuItemManager.Find(x => x.Main == true); - на этом этапе коллекцию я получаю, теперь пытаюсь дотянуться до item.MenuItems - тут падаю с вышеуказанным эксепшеном

Comment: Обращаюсь в контроллере.

Comment: Вы в `using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())` открываете новую сессию, получаете список без собственно MenuItem-ов и сессия завершается этим самым using-ом. О своем желании что-то догрузить хиберу надо сообщать в той же сессии, где получаете сами элементы.

Comment: Нет, одна сессия открыта до protected void Application_EndRequest()